# Problema ao gravar os dados da ComboBox no Postgresql

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql

Primeiro este é o código do banco que estou utilizando:

```
CREATE TABLE perguntas (
    cod_pergunta SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    pergunta VARCHAR(500),
    opcao_um  VARCHAR(500),
    opcao_dois VARCHAR(500),
    opcao_tres VARCHAR(500),
    opcao_quatro VARCHAR(500),
    opcao_correta INTEGER,
    IDcategoria INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT fk_categoria FOREIGN KEY (IDcategoria) REFERENCES categoria(cod_categoria)
);

CREATE TABLE categoria (
    cod_categoria SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    categoria VARCHAR(15),
    descricao VARCHAR(140)
);
```

Eu consigo gravar os valores na tabela perguntas porém o valor do combobox 'categoria' está gravando errado quando tento gravar o primeiro valor.

Imagem do formulário:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do botão Gravar:

```
    private void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//Verifica qual radio button está selecionado
            int valor;
            valor = 0;
            if (rbCorreta1.Checked == true)
                valor = 1;
            else if (rbCorreta2.Checked == true)
                valor = 2;
            else if (rbCorreta3.Checked == true)
                valor = 3;
            else if (rbCorreta4.Checked == true)
                valor = 4;
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Selecione a resposta correta!");


//Verifica qual o valor do combobox está selecionado e guarda o ID para gravar
            string IndexSelecionado = cbCategoria.SelectedIndex.ToString();



            string str = "Host=127.0.0.1;Username=postgres;Password=adm;Database=dbquiz";
            string gravarsql = "INSERT INTO perguntas (pergunta, opcao_um, opcao_dois, opcao_tres, opcao_quatro, opcao_correta, idcategoria) " + " VALUES ('" + txtPergunta.Text + "', '" + txtResposta1.Text + "', '" + txtResposta2.Text + "', '" + txtResposta3.Text + "', '" + txtResposta4.Text + "', '" + valor + "', '"+ IndexSelecionado + "');";
            Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection con = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(str);
            Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand cmd = new Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand(gravarsql, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            con.Open();

            try
            {
                int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (n > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Efetuado!");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

O erro que aparece é este abaixo, porém só acontece quando quero gravar o 1º valor do combobox porque os demais da pra gravar só que grava o index errado:

Ex.

categorias: 1-Teste, 2-Foo, 3-Stack;
Quando seleciono o 2, grava o 3.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código para preencher o Combobox:

```
string str = "Host=127.0.0.1;Username=postgres;Password=adm;Database=dbquiz";
            Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection con = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(str);
            con.Open();

            try
            {
                string sql = "SELECT categoria.cod_categoria, categoria.categoria FROM categoria;";
                Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand cmd = new Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);
                Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(reader);

                this.cbCategoria.DataSource = dt;

                this.cbCategoria.DisplayMember = "categoria";
                this.cbCategoria.ValueMember = "cod_categoria";

                reader.Close();
                reader.Dispose();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: Jovem, tem como postar também o código que usa para preencher o combobox?

Comment: Beleza, irei atualizar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você está usando o `SelectedIndex` como o valor de categoria, só que não necessariamente estes valores (index do combobox e id da tabela) serão correspondentes. Na verdade, é muito difícil que isso aconteça.

O que você precisa salvar é o **Id da categoria selecionada**. Como você preenche o combobox com `DisplayMember` e `ValueMember`, pode apenas alterar uma linha de código para resolver isso.

Esta linha

```
string IndexSelecionado = cbCategoria.SelectedIndex.ToString();
```

Deveria ser

```
string IndexSelecionado = cbCategoria.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Aliás, seria bom também mudar o nome da variável para não ficar confuso, mas isso é com você.

---

Acho importante comentar que você está fazendo um mau uso das exceções mostrando apenas a mensagem dela. Uma das coisas que você mais vai precisar quando tiver ocorrendo uma exceção na aplicação é o *stacktrace* (que está sendo ignorado) para poder rastreá-la.

Outra coisa é que seria legal separar as responsabilidades da aplicação, fazer a conexão com o banco em um lugar apenas e reaproveitar isso em outros lugares. Isso evita bastante repetição de código e ajuda na manutenção mais tarde.

Claro que estes não são pontos principais da pergunta, só achei importante citá-los.

Comment: Funcionou mano, porém me explica uma coisa,  SelectedIndex não pega o valor da ID cadastrada no banco então?

Comment: Não. Ele captura o Index do item selecionado no ComboBox. Ou seja, se o mesmo que o primeiro elemento seja a categoria com Id = 500, o valor de `SelectedIndex` vai ser **`0`**. Entende? Ele é sempre sequencial, começando em 0.  O primeiro item é o `0` e assim por diante.

Comment: Agradeço, ficou claro pra mim agora! Obrigado.

Comment: Irei começar aprender POO pra melhorar este código, por enquanto só estou testando outras coisas.. se pude me recomendar algo, seria legal

Comment: @WSS Tranquilo, enquanto tá começando a estudar é melhor focar numa coisa de cada vez mesmo. Depende de o que vc precisa posso te ajudar. Sempre que precisar de alguma dica, pode também falar com o pessoal no [chat].